# does not provide an export named 'BrowserQRCodeReader'

Tags: javascript, qr-code, zxing, lit-element, lit-html

I am using zxing-js/library library for qr code reading. I am facing a strange issue. The code for the qr scanning works in stackblitz online sample code, but not in my local environment.
I am getting this error in local environment on run time. The compilation proceeds successfully.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/node_modules/@zxing/library/esm5/index.js' does not provide an export named 'BrowserQRCodeReader'
```

stackblitz [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/naxw5o-qtyvc4?file=custom-greeting.js)

github [link](https://github.com/abidhkm/qr-dode-reader-zxing)

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the `zxing-js/library` has issues with bundling.

I can reproduce the error by running `npm run build`, followed by `npm run start`. 
Looks like some bundling would be required for you to get this working in the browser. See [this post](https://github.com/Polymer/lit-html/issues/515) for more info

In the meantime, you can use `npm run start:dev`, and you will be able to do local development as expected.

Thanks [@passle_](https://twitter.com/passle_) from the @open-wc team for helping with this.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to jlengrands answer, `npm start` will start the `owc-dev-server` which does a minimal amount of work; it'll only resolve the bare modules.

The QR code library that you're trying to use uses commonjs, it'll need a little magic to be transformed so the browser can understand that code. The webpack-dev-server can do this for you, which you can run with `npm run start:dev`.